# Setting the default NSView fill colour using a variable

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsview

I am trying to fill my `NSView` with a colour, but it is not using the colour I want. It's just black.

This is my implementation for a subclass of NSView:

```
#import "OCOvalView.h"

@implementation OCOvalView

- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        bgColorValue = [NSColor greenColor];//I WANT IT TO BE FILLED GREEN
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    [bgColorValue set];
    [NSBezierPath fillRect:[self bounds]];//BUT IT ENDS UP BLACK!!
}

@end
```

It will work if I change `[bgColorValue set];` to `[[NSColor greenColor] set];`, but I want to use a variable as shown above.

How do I get the fill the same colour as `bgColorData`'s colour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:** Since I was setting `bgColorValue` within `initWithFrame:frame`, it was not being called in this case. I now set the variable as such:

```
-(void)awakeFromNib{
    bgColorValue = [NSColor greenColor];
}
```